# how to kick all in a guild?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to kick everyone in my guild with this code:

```js
const { GuildMember } = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    description: "Kick a member of the guild.",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        message.guild.members.forEach((user) => guild.members.kick(user.id));
    },
};
```

But I'm getting the error `TypeError: message.guild.members.forEach is not a function`. I have no clue how to fix this and wondering if anyone here knows?

Answer (score 0):

Discord JS v12 introduces the concept of managers, you will no longer be able to directly use collection methods such as Collection#get on data structures like Client#users or Guild#members.

You will now have to directly ask for a cache on a manager before trying to use collection methods.

---

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach((GuildMember) => GuildMember.kick())
```